# MongoDB replica set on single machine

Tags: mongodb

I have a single instance (I.e. no virtualisation) of Linux running on a server. I have a single `mongod` instance that is running. Moving to production I want to implement replica sets. Everything I've read talks about running `mongod` on multiple machines.

I understand it might not be best practice however is it possible to run replica sets of the same machine. Also, the machine has two hard drives. I want the primary DB to be on the first HD and the replica set on the second hard drive.

Is this setup possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Just run instances on different ports. It is quite common for development, and there is https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools/wiki/mlaunch to automate it. The question is why would you need it in production? Replication comes at cost, and you are going to pay it without any benefits.

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm trying to work out the best way to backup the database files :S I was actually just thinking of scheduling a cron job to copy the database files over to the second HD however I read this might cause problems (in terms of data integrity). I don't mind if i miss information that's still in memory from mongo that hasn't been written yet. As long as the database files will load. But I'm not sure this will be the case? journaling is enabled so would it be simple possible to 'cp db1 /mnt/hd2/d1' or would I need to lock db.fsyncLock() first? The problem with locking in production though

Comment: is that mongod will block writes until i copy and unlock.

Comment: So why not to ask the straight question? =) You are falling into http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: To answer your real question, consider https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-with-mongodump

Comment: Hi Alex I have considered this however I have a book "MongoDB The definitive guide Second Edition" that states the following: "If you have unique index (other than"_id") on any of your collections, you should consider using a different type of backup than mongodump/mongostore. Specifically, unique indexes require that the data does not change in ways that would violate  the unique index constraint  during the copy. The safest way to do this is to choose a method that 'freezes' the data, then take a backup." Now to be honest I don't really understand this but i am using unique indexes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137424/discussion-between-xenophon-and-alex-blex).

Comment: Late to the party, but I'll try to clear up the same question I had - replication in production, is most of the time only useful when running multiple nodes on different servers. The point of having slaves is that they can function instead of the master, if the master (i.e. master server) goes down. If you want to run a replication set on the same server - just for backing up data - go with mongodump or any other backup-approach. If you intend to run different nodes on different disks, on the same server - you're not gaining much, you just end up having a failover in case of a faulty disk...

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I did it on Ubuntu. I wanted to use systemd for the second instance.

Copy our existing MongoDB conf:

`sudo cp /etc/mongod.conf /etc/mongod_repl.conf`

`sudo pico /etc/mongod_repl.conf`

Change these lines:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb_repl

systemLog:
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod_repl.log

net:
  port: 27018

replication:
  replSetName: rs0
```

Create the dirs and files, and assign permissions

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb_repl
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb_repl
sudo touch /var/log/mongodb/mongod_repl.log
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/mongod_repl.log
```

Copy our existing startup file:

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service /etc/systemd/system/mongod_repl.service
```

If you can't find mongod.service, `sudo systemctl status mongod`. It looks like:

*Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)*

`sudo pico /etc/systemd/system/mongod_repl.service`

Change these lines:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod_repl.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod_repl.pid
```

Let systemctl know we've made some changes:
`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Try start it our second server:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod_repl
sudo systemctl status mongod_repl
```

If it's not running, have a look at the logs:

```
sudo tail -n100 /var/log/mongodb/mongod_repl.log
sudo journalctl -n100 -u mongod_repl
```

(You can add a `-f` to either of those lines to tail the log)

Log in
`mongo --port 27018`

Great! Now you have a second MongoDB server up and running.

Configure your original server to use the same replication set:
`sudo pico /etc/mongod.conf`

Add this:

```
replication:
   replSetName: rs0
```

Restart MongoDB
`sudo systemctl restart mongod`

Now you should be able to go through the process of rs.initiate() on your primary, and then add `127.0.0.1:27018` as your secondary.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to get the replica set up and running on a single machine and this is how I do it for testing:

1. Install mongodb-org on your machine by following [the official instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) and make sure it is starting fine.
2. Then stop the instance process: `sudo systemctl stop mongod`
3. You can now start a new instance with --replSet option by following [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/). Also, in order to have it running in the background you can use --fork and --logpath to create a child process:

   ```
   mongod --fork --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongo_0.log --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,<Your machine's IP address>
   ```
4. Then connect to the instance and initiate the replica set in Mongo shell:

   ```
   mongo --port 27017
   >rs.initiate()
   ```
5. In case you want to stop the process do `ps aux | grep mongod` and then `kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

1. Create a script: `sudo nano mongod.sh`
2. Copy and paste:

```
sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all &
sudo mongod --port 27018 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb2 --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all &
sudo mongod --port 27019 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb3 --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all &
```

3. Permit the script to execute:
   `sudo chmod +x mongod.sh`
4. Run the script:
   `./mongod.sh`
5. Initialize replica set in primary mongo server:

```
$ mongo
> rs.initiate()

output
{
 "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
 "me" : "<<YOUR_IP>>:27017",
 "ok" : 1
}
rs0:SECONDARY> rs.add('<<YOUR_IP>>:27018')
{ "ok" : 1 }
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add('<<YOUR_IP>>:27019')
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

> Now, test with your connection string.

**Connection String**

```
mongodb://<YOUR_IP>:27017,<YOUR_IP>:27018,<YOUR_IP>:27019/<DB>?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondary
```

Note: If you're testing in a local system, then remove `--bind_ip_all` option for security reasons.

### Options

> ```
> --port: Specify port
> --dbpath: Path where the mongod instance stores its data
> --replSet: Replica set name
> --bind_ip_all: Allow remote connections
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I did these actions in mongodb 7 to setup two secondary replica and then setup authorization for them:

1. copy from main config file:

```
sudo cp /etc/mongod.conf /etc/mongod_repl1.conf
sudo cp /etc/mongod.conf /etc/mongod_repl2.conf
```

2. change replica config files:

```
nano /etc/mongod_repl1.conf
```

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb_repl1

systemLog:
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod_repl1.log

net:
  port: 27018

replication:
  replSetName: rs0
```

```
nano /etc/mongod_repl2.conf
```

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb_repl2

systemLog:
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod_repl2.log

net:
  port: 27019

replication:
  replSetName: rs0
```

3. Create directories and set permissions:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb_repl1
sudo touch /var/log/mongodb/mongod_repl1.log
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb_repl2
sudo touch /var/log/mongodb/mongod_repl2.log
sudo chown mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongodb_repl*
sudo chown mongod:mongod /var/log/mongodb/mongod_repl*.log
```

4. copy service file:

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service /etc/systemd/system/mongod_repl1.service
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service /etc/systemd/system/mongod_repl2.service
```

and then change the config files and update these lines to appropriate configs:

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/mongod_repl1.service
```

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod_repl1.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod_repl1.pid
```

5. update systemctl

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

6. start services:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod_repl1
sudo systemctl start mongod_repl2
```

get status:

```
sudo systemctl status mongod_repl1
```

if service is running then enable service to auto start when system rebooted:

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod_repl1
sudo systemctl enable mongod_repl2
```

7. update main mongod config file (replication section)
   nano /etc/mongod.conf

```
replication:
   replSetName: rs0
```

8. restart mongod service
9. connect to mongod and add replica

```
# mongosh
rs.initiate()
rs.add({ host: "127.0.0.1:27018" })
rs.add({ host: "127.0.0.1:27019" })
```

### Now try to set user,pass for mongodb

```
# mongosh

use admin

db.createUser("admin",pwd: passwordPrompt(),{roles:["clusterManager","root","userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase"]})
```

then create ssl key for communicate between replica sets

```
openssl rand -base64 741 > /etc/mongodb.key
chmod 600 /etc/mongodb.key
chown mongod:mongod /etc/mongodb.key
```

update all mongod config files (3 files) like below lines

```
nano /etc/mongod.conf
nano /etc/mongod_repl1.conf
nano /etc/mongod_repl2.conf
```

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0

security:
  authorization: enabled
  keyFile: /etc/mongodb.key
```

restart all services (3 services)

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
sudo systemctl restart mongod_repl1
sudo systemctl restart mongod_repl2
```

if you want to set first mongod as primary everytime, you can set priority for each replica to rs.conf() like this:

```
{
  _id: 'rs0',
  version: 9,
  term: 28,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: '127.0.0.1:27017',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 1,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long('0'),
      votes: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      host: '127.0.0.1:27018',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 0.5,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long('0'),
      votes: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      host: '127.0.0.1:27019',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 0.5,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long('0'),
      votes: 1
    }
  ],
  protocolVersion: Long('1'),
  writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault: true,
  settings: {
    chainingAllowed: true,
    heartbeatIntervalMillis: 2000,
    heartbeatTimeoutSecs: 10,
    electionTimeoutMillis: 10000,
    catchUpTimeoutMillis: -1,
    catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis: 30000,
    getLastErrorModes: {},
    getLastErrorDefaults: { w: 1, wtimeout: 0 },
    replicaSetId: ObjectId('65c20af84386cf3ce2be6e86')
  }
}
```